# Referencing different versions of Json.NET dll

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json.net

I am playing with my mvc project.

1. I Nugeted a package called SocialAuth.Net into the project, which in turn uses Newtonsoft.Json.dll 4.0.0.0 (older) as one of its dependencies.
2. Then because I also needed Json.Net myself, I wanted a newer version, So I Nugeted Json.NET, which has a newer version 4.5.0.0 (newer).

Then problem happens. In my razor view "ViewBag.Title = ...." it has red underline saying:

> Warning 1 c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\WebApp\WebApp\Views\Home\Index.cshtml: ASP.NET runtime
>   error: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json,
>   Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or
>   one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition
>   does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131040)

This is the Json part of my web.config:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.5.0.0" newVersion="4.5.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

So,

1. I went to References, checked and found Newtonsoft.Json was 4.0.0.0 (probably came with SocialAuth.Net), and I deleted it, and added the 4.5.0.0 reference I got from Nuget.
2. I went into WebApp/bin/debug/ folder and deleted everything, and then rebuilt the project.

However, once I rebuild the webapp, the Newton.Json 4.0.0.0 comes back into bin/debug/ regardless how I manually reference it to the new Nuget 4.5.0.0. and the same error comes back. I am stuck.

Do you have and idea how to deal with this dll issue? Thank you.

EDIT -----------------------------------

After a bit of thinking, I understand it is because first Json.Net (newer 4.5) is linked first, then the older one comes after it when building. So the older one overwrites the newer one.

I am not fimiliar with GAC installing, but know I could open that can of worms and install 2 versions there, which I don't want to, because that means I have to do that to every machine I deploy the web app. Is there a way to play with the web.config and get around this?

Comment: oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.5.0.0" should be oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to install the SocialAuth.Net package with the [`‑IgnoreDependencies`](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/package-manager-console-powershell-reference) flag, then installing the dependencies manually and making sure that you only install the latest version of Json.Net library.

Then at runtime the SocialAuth.Net package would respect the assembly redirect and load Json.Net (v4.5) instead of the old version.

Comment: Tested it just now. The "-IgnoreDependencies" command doesn't seem to do anything to the package. It just overwrites the new version Json.Net 4.5 with its 4.0 anyway.

Comment: Did you uninstall the packages in question first? If possible, uninstall all packages first and then install them again with the switch. I never used that particularly switch myself but from the docs it should not do what you described.

Comment: I started it all over again. Confirmed that SocialAuth.Net ignored the "-IgnoreDependencies" command, brought its own dependencies with it with a fresh download. Then overwritten my newer dependencies with the old ones. being Json.Net and log4net.... Also noticed that if I go Nuget manager UI and check SocialAuth.Net Dependencies under its description, it says "null". May be SocialAuth.Net didn't associate its dependencies with Nuget and/or hardwired it somehow?

Comment: I got an idea. I will go to SocialAuth.Net download the source code and compile it myself. And fix anything if it breaks. It only works in this particular case. If we have a dll dependency without source code, then I don't know how to get around that. It is likely to happen, e.g. something uses Windsor.1.2.3 other 3rd party dll uses Windsor 2.3.4, then I will come back to this issue again.

Comment: I'm out of ideas so in lack of a better option the only option always seems nice. :)